# Fragment Add causing me an error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to figure out why I am suddenly getting an error when I try to add a fragment.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Communicator {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView((int) R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragA, new FragmentA()); 
        //I get errors on each of the adds
        ft.commit();
        FragmentTransaction ft2 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft2.add(R.id.fragB, new FragmentB());
        ft2.commit();
        FragmentTransaction ft3 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft3.add(R.id.fragC, new FragmentC());
        ft3.commit();
    }

    public void respond(String str) {
        //I also get an error on the following line       
        ((FragmentB)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragB)).changeText(str);
    }
}
```

Just using the import of `FragmentTransaction`, I haven't made my own class.

This is my fragment A code:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    Button btn;
    Communicator comm;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fraga, container, false);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        this.btn = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
        this.btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.comm = (Communicator) getActivity();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        this.comm.respond("Hello from Fragment A");
    }
}
```

xml for the activity, I am not a hundred percent sure if this will fix it but would raising the API of the project make any difference at all?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout          
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.tannerlangan.week11fragtalk.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#ff83ff3e"
    android:id="@+id/fragA"></RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#ff71e7ff"
    android:id="@+id/fragB"></RelativeLayout>

   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#ff6d9aff"
    android:id="@+id/fragC"></RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What's the error and where does it appear in the code?

Comment: the eror appears on all of the ft.add lines and it is 'cannot resolve method add(int com.name)'

Comment: Can we see your `FragmentTransaction` class then please?

Comment: @Draken FragmentTransaction is an api class not created by user

Comment: show your FragmentA class code

Comment: I showed FragmentA

Comment: why your fragment methods are not overrided one?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you are asking

Comment: onCreateView() should be overrided method from Fragment class and not your own method

Comment: oh I gotcha, I fixed that but that did not seem to make any difference

Comment: same issue is with your activity class. onCreate() is also not overrided

Comment: Can you create your Fragments outside your methods instead of inside of them, e.g. `FragmentB b = new FragmentB(); ft2.add(R.id.fragB, b);`

Comment: I changed all of them to be like that

Comment: Adding the override tag won't do much here @Vivek, it will only point out if the `@Override` was done incorrectly. Classes will auto override without the tag, if applicable

Comment: @Draken when doing that it gives me the same error, I am really confused because in the previous version of my code it was like this and worked, I don't know what changed now though

Comment: @Draken but if they are not overriden they will not get called by the system and probably if that error goes away, then also onCreate() will not get called as it is not being called manually

Comment: would it be because I am using a lower api now?

Comment: @Kiotzu add your activity xml file also

Comment: @VivekMishra I have added the xml file

Comment: I think you have to change your approach a bit. If you don't have to replace fragment that you have added, then instead of relative layouts you can directly use fragment tag and then there will be no need of Fragment Transaction

Comment: Here is an example of doing it the above way http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fragments probably using a`ndroid.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `android.app.Fragment`. The quick fix is to change the signature of your fragments to something like this:

```
public class FragmentA extends android.app.Fragment implements OnClickListener
```

This is very common with programs that mix the components from support libraries and the non-support one

Comment: Thank you!,this was exactly the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager(). getSupportFragmentManager() is for API<14.

Comment: I'm still above 15, I'm using 17

Answer (score 0):

In your project check whether you have imported the same Fragment class in both your FragmentA and MainActivity.  You might have imported **android.support.v4.app.Fragment** in your fragment and in MainActivity you may have imported **android.app.Fragment**.

If you're minSdk is <14 use fragment, fragmentManager etc from the support library(i.e android.support.v4.app.fragment and same for the fragment manager) else just import the standard fragment class(i.e android.app.Fragment).

**P.S** : It would be really helpfull if you provide your Error in the question as well.